# How can I import a CLion C++ project into Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clion

It seems like this should be easy and I've spent hours trying to find this answer online but haven't had any luck.

I can open the CLion folder path in Visual Studio, but that option doesn't give me the usual options to build and start the project. To do that, I need to open CLion as a Project/Solution, but I can't seem to do this.

My professor requires that my C++ code be executable in Visual Studio, but I prefer CLion. So I've done all my work in CLion and want to test that it runs in Visual Studio. How can I import my CLion project?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are using cmake as build system generator, and you can use cmake in visual studio too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: Each IDE has project configuration allowing you to add libraries, both object files and include files, by configuring library -L and include -I directories, as well as library names -l, so that your references to them in your code are valid, just as they are for the standard libraries.  The challenge with an IDE is getting it not only to compile but to make the IDE happy, too!  What sort of road block are you experiencing?

Comment: Doesn't `CLion` use `CMake`? if so `CMake` also supports generating Visual Studio Solutions.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, it uses CMake. Do you know how I can generate the Visual Studio Solutions?

Comment: One way is to install CMake and use cmake-gui to generate a Visual Studio project file. The other is in the first comment of this question.

Comment: @Equod I must be missing something because I still can't get this to work. Here's what I did:

1) Open a local folder
2) Select folder that contains CMake
3) I get error messages in the console. They start with:  1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:173 (file):
1> [CMake]   file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):
4) The link you provided gives instructions for "Build CMake Project". None of the options are available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link provided describes [Visual Studio's CMake integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), which (similar to CLion) will install a version of CMake that Visual Studio will use. These instructions are pretty thorough and should provide everything needed to get your CMake project working in Visual Studio.

Now, you probably have *two* versions of CMake installed on your machine, one that came with CLion and one that came with Visual Studio. I would recommend installing the *latest* version of [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) on your machine **separately**, and configuring both Visual Studio and CLion to use *that* version instead. However, this is probably getting outside the scope of your immediate problem.

---

As you follow the Microsoft's instructions for ["CMake projects in Visual Studio"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), you mentioned receiving the error:

```
1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:173 (file): 
1> [CMake] file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):
```

This looks like a **permissions** issue, specifically while running CMake within Visual Studio, so be sure you have read/write access to all the files in your project, and the CMake packages in your Visual Studio installation. Hopefully, this doesn't require you re-install Visual Studio in another location on your machine, or run Visual Studio with elevated privileges, but perhaps that is necessary.

---

If you decide to install CMake **separately**, the instructions would be the following:

1. Install the latest CMake on your machine (somewhere you have adequate permissions), and ensure it is available in your `Path` environment variable. You can verify this by running `cmake -version` from the command line to see it is the version you just installed.
2. Using Windows command prompt, navigate to your CMake project directory (containing the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file), and run the following:

   ```
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ..
   ```

   You may run `-A Win32` with the `cmake` command instead if your project is a 32-bit build.
3. Open the `.sln` Visual Studio Solution file that was generated in the `build` directory. Once, the Solution is loaded in Visual Studio, you can build the project (**CTRL + SHIFT + B**).